# Blazor server , websocket disconnected 1006 (no reason given) when calling the application by hostname

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have an ASP.NET Core Blazor server application hosted on IIS. When I call by hostname, it returns a websocket error, however calling by local ip address, the websocket connects successfully.

Please see the two screenshots:

Calling by host name:

[image: by host name]

Calling by IP address:

[image: by local address]

Comment: set firewall to allow the connection with the port number 5050

Comment: I did , but iam still facing the same issue.

Comment: are you accessing site on same machine where it is hosted or outside of the network?

Comment: it is hosted on IIS as back end , and the sub domain pointining to the local IP , both on same network , i discussed with the network team and they said the port is opened and accessible

Comment: verify that the SSL/TLS certificate is valid and properly installed. check application logs by enabling detailed errors in the ASP.NET Core application settings this can give some information. another test you can do is try testing the default site of iis accessing it with the same doin configuration to see there is no issue in it.

Comment: thanks for your help , it was a configuration in proxy to allow websocket .